# How to add openCV on PyCharm under rpi 3 B?

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries

I am trying to add OpenCV lib on PyCharm running under Raspbian on a Rpi 3 model B. I tried the jessie version of commands but got stuck on the

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Got the message:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi/BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON" does not exist.

Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I am new to Raspberry Pi and never played with the jessie version of Raspbian (using Strech). I am almost sure it might be a usage error from my ignorance on the language.

Comment: I have tried to install PyCharn on my RasPi 400. It worked, but PyCharm need much more juice than the Pi can provide. It is very slow and barely usable. I would reccomend you to Not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have old stable version jessie running but usually you find `libopencv*` in the default Raspbian repositories. Look with `apt list libopencv*` if it is available in jessie. If so you can simply install the libraries you need. There is no need to compile `OpenCV` from source, unless you must use a newer version.